# How to add a dependency to another project properly using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, project-structure

Hello I am new to gradle and it is a little bit confusing for me. How should I add a dependency in my gradle configuration to have access to *B1.java* in *projectA1*? Project B is gradle project and project A is just a folder with another gradle projects.

Here is my structure:

1. Workspace:

   - ProjectA

     - projectA1

       - ...
       - **here I want to have access to *B1.java***
       - build.gradle
     - projectA2

       - ...
       - build.gradle
   - ProjectB

     - projectB1

       - *B1.java*
       - ...
       - build.gradle
     - projectB2

       - ...
       - build.gradle
     - build.gradle

I tried to read gradle documentation, but it is not clear for me. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/) post.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should have a structure like this:

```
ProjectA
|--projectA1
|----build.gradle
|--projectA2
|----build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--build.gradle

ProjectB
|--projectB1
|----build.gradle
|--projectB2
|----build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--build.gradle
```

You can link an external module in your project.

1) In your project `projectA/settings.gradle`

```
include ':projectA1',':projectA2',':projectB1' 
project(':projectB1').projectDir = new File("/workspace/projectB/projectB1")
```

2) Add dependency in `build.gradle` of `projectA1` module

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':projectB1')
}
```

Comment: I followed the above approach, the exception was that projectB1 had a dependency on projectB2, something like ```evaluationDependsOn(':projectB2')``` and thus in my projectA1 if I include projectB1, it throws an error like :projectB2 does not exist. Is there a smart way to fix this other than adding projectB2 also as  a subproject in ProjectA?

Comment: If you are using  `evaluationDependsOn(':projectB2')`, you have to declare `:projectB2` otherwise gradle doesn't know what is projectB2.

Comment: But lets say if ProjectB1 depends on other, say 5 subprojects in ProjectB. Then in that case, I will have to declare all the subprojects in projectA right?

Comment: @KumarShubham yes, the alternative is to change some gradle script if it is possible and try to centralize some tasks in order to reuse them.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! However, two things had to be changed for me to make this work: `implementation` instead of `compile` for `dependencies{}` (suggested by Android Studio) and `.setProjectDir()` in `settings.gradle`.

Comment: My `ProjectA` doesn't recognize `ProjectB.buildSrc` for some reason, do I need to add it explicitly somehow?

Comment: I'll add that this answer is coded in groovy, you'll need to add parenthesis around the arguments to `include` and `implementation`.  Additionally, you can be more sure of your file directory by calling `File(settingsDir, "path/from/settings/file")`

Answer (score 5):

Unless if projects A1 and B1 live in the same source repository and are checked-out and checked-in together, you really should depend on project B1 as an external dependency.

in Project A1 build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'projectB1group:projectB1module:projectB1version'
}
```

Of course, for this to work, you will have had to publish B1 binaries to a repository that is accessible from Project A1 first. This can either be a external nexus/artifactory type maven repository, but can also be your local maven .m2 cache, or even a plain old file system. For maven publishing see `maven` or 'maven-publish` plugins.

---

If both projects live in the same source repo, you should organize ProjectA and ProjectB as subprojects under a root "container" project. The root project does not need to have source code of its own.

Read about organizing multi-project builds in gradle [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

If the root project has a `settings.gradle` with include lines that includes project B1, you can refer to any project under the root project like this:

```
project(':B1')
```

so, to add B1 as a dependency to A1, in A1's build.gradle:

```
compile project('B1')
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit [setting.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) in root path and include your sub projects, and then subproject will be able to see and depend on each other.

```
root
 |-- build.gradle << very simple bulid.grade , no special thing.
 |-- setting.gradle <<
```

```
rootProject.name = 'root'

file("${rootDir}/ProjectA").eachDirMatch(~/.*/) {
    include "ProjectA:${it.name}"
}

file("${rootDir}/ProjectB").eachDirMatch(~/.*/) {
    include "ProjectB:${it.name}"
}
```

2. `build.gradle` in project

```
root
 |-- ProjectA
        |-- projectA1
            |-- build.gradle  <<
```

```
implementation project(':ProjectB:projectB1')
```

Ref:

- You can this [setting.gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/settings.gradle) in spring project
- Official documentation : [Declaring Dependencies between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html)
- Official documentation : [setting.gradle and demo](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html)

Comment: point 2: it should be 'build.gradle' and not 'build.setting'. Also could you please explain what does it include "orm:${it.name}" mean and for project B why its web?