# Gradle can't find local dependency project

Tags: java, gradle, multi-project

I have this Gradle project:

```
G:\!Modding\jtta-primitive-lite
```

And it should have this dependency (also a Gradle project):

```
G:\!Modding\jtta-core
```

`jtta-primitive-lite` should depend on `jtta-core` project (without including)

I made like this for `jtta-primitive-lite` :

```
    repositories {      
        flatDir {
            dirs '../'
        }
    }
    
    
    dependencies {
        
        //modApi "jtta-core:jtta-core:"
        modApi project("jtta-core").projectDir = new File("../jtta-core")
        // Also tried new File("../")
        //api project(":jtta-core").projectDir = new File("../")
    }
```

But its searches only inside root directory:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Build file 'G:\!Modding\jtta-primitive-lite\build.gradle' line: 34
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'jtta-primitive-lite'.
    > Project with path 'jtta-core' could not be found in root project 'jtta-primitive-lite'.
```

I don't know why. If you need additional info, I can get it.

Also i tried to `includeBuild("../jtta-core")` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606790/how-to-add-a-dependency-to-another-project-properly-using-gradle

Comment: I change my structure but it wont help

Now jtta-core suits in jtta-primitive-lite

Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':jtta-core' could not be found in root project 'jtta-primitive-lite'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to mock up an example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64438893). Note that it uses relative paths, not absolute paths, but that shouldn't be a big deal. The layout is:

```
settings.gradle
./G_modding/jtta-core/build.gradle
./G_modding/jtta-primitive-lite/build.gradle
```

The `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':G_modding:jtta-primitive-lite', ':G_modding:jtta-core'
```

and this `build.gradle` in `G_modding/jtta-primitive-lite`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    implementation project(":G_modding:jtta-core")
}
```

Hopefully that is enough to illustrate the issue? (I don't know your specific goal, so I don't know the precise problem).

Comment: Yes. Thanks for helping me!
There is some very specific problem with gradle plugin that i use but i think i can handle it. Thank you!